# searchCriteria unavailable in Flight Availabilities Search

Tags: python, api, amadeus

Using `searchCriteria` in the body JSON doesn't seem to work for me.

If I remove it, it works just fine, but as soon as I add it, it gives me a 500 error.

[The API documentation](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-availabilities-search/api-reference) states that searchCriteria should be possible to use, and I am interested in using the `flightFilters` part. This is the code I inserted into my query JSON:

```
  "searchCriteria": {
    "flightFilters": {
      "carrierRestrictions": {
        "includedCarrierCodes": ["UA","AA"]
      }
    }
  }
```

The same piece of code works well on the Flight Offer Search. I noticed that `flightFilters` for the Availability Search seem to be a trimmed down version (it says `FlightFiltersLight`), although I don't think it's related to my issue.

Is this part not implemented yet or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Hello! Indeed there is a bug in the search criteria. A workaround is to add a maxNumberOfConnections in the request with the value 0,1 or 2 as in the example https://gist.github.com/tsolakoua/b44c410b252d3448ead9f61035456e8a until we fix it.

Comment: Ok, understood. Thank you very much!

Comment: The issue has been fixed.